# Summarize using related table and 2 conditional columns

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, measure

I have two tables . I have created a table visual in power BI where I am combining the two values eg below :

Table 1 :

| Site Name | Type | Area(m2) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hospital | 50 |
| A | Education | 100 |
| B | Tech Lab | 20 |
| B | Office | 70 |
| B | Education | 90 |

Table 2 :

| Type | Usage (hr/m2) | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Hospital | 100 | Low |
| Education | 500 | Low |
| Tech Lab | 50 | Low |
| Office | 200 | Low |

This visual also has a slicer:

| Usage Type |
| --- |
| Low |
| Medium |
| High |

The slicer currently chosen is lets say "Low"

On my PowerBI visual ( a table) I am merging this two tables by "Type" to give me

| Site Name | Type | Area | Usage(hr/m2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Hospital | 50 | 100 |
| A | Education | 100 | 500 |
| B | Tech Lab | 20 | 50 |
| B | Office | 70 | 200 |
| B | Education | 90 | 500 |

The end goal is to find the usage by site. In my head the equation should be  :

For A :

```
TotalUsage[A] = Area[Hospital] * Usage[Hospital] + Area[Education] * Usage[Education] 
    = 50 x 100 + 100 x 500 = 55000

TotalArea[A] = Area[Hospital] + Area[Education] = 150

Usage[A] = TotalUsage[A] / TotalArea[A] 
    = 55000 / 150 = 366 hr/m2
```

How can I achieve this ?

I first created the visual as shown above(third table)

I did quick measures for total usage for each row. The displayed that on the third table.

However when I try to measure again , this type only grouped by Site, instead of following the above equation it sums the usage rows first (so 100+500=600), then sums the area ( 50+100=150) and then calculates the usage for site A giving 600/150 ( which is wrong! )

Answer (score 0):

Use these measures:

```
Area Usage = 
SUMX(
    'Table 1',
    'Table 1'[Area(m2)] * LOOKUPVALUE(
        'Table 2'[Usage (hr/m2)],
        'Table 2'[Type], SELECTEDVALUE('Table 1'[Type]),
        'Table 2'[Usage Type], SELECTEDVALUE('Table 2'[Usage Type])
    )
)
```

```
Total Usage = 
SUMX(
    VALUES('Table 1'[Type]), 
    [Area Usage]
)
```

```
Total Area = SUM('Table 1'[Area(m2)])
```

```
Usage = DIVIDE([Total Usage], [Total Area]))
```

and put everything together in a table

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you so much , I tried this measure but it will not work as the related table 2 has multiple values for one row from table 1 and therefore its linked to a slicer selection. How can  we ensure that the sumx calculates the total usage based on the slicer selection?

Comment: Yep, your sample data didn't cover that case. Now, since you can't establish a relation between the 2 tables, you have to use LOOKUPVALUE instead, see my edit.

Comment: Didn't my answer solve your problem now?